# How can i put popover to one element with different selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the jquery.gantt plugin in my web app, but in the example comes the code to see popups, but in only one popup for all the elements in the gantt.

I want to show different popup for each element

Example:

Element1 - Title: Promo 1 Content: This promo is awesome
Element1 - Title: Promo 2 Content: This promo is not awesome

in the example only comes this code:

```
        $(".gantt").popover({
            selector: ".bar",
            title: "Promocion #1",
            content: "Bono 2x1 miembros cobrand",
            trigger: "hover"
        });
```

I want use the same but depends of differents selectors:

```
        $(".gantt").popover({
            selector: ".promo1",
            title: "Promocion #1",
            content: "Bono 2x1 miembros cobrand",
            trigger: "hover"
        });


        $(".gantt").popover({
            selector: ".promo2",
            title: "Promocion #2",
            content: "BonASDASDASDros cobrand",
            trigger: "hover"
        });
```

But is not working, somebody knows why? or what can i do to get the result that i want.

Thanks a lot.
I'm from el salvador so, sorry for my bad english

Comment: can u give a fiddle?if ok,